# Rails 3 - No Route Matches Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This is my first question to stackoverflow, and I feel a bit daft having not been able to fix the bug myself, but here goes.

I'm attempting to connect a link on a pages index to an edit action and I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"pages"}
```

So obviously I first checked the controller - there's definitely an edit action in there!

Here's my relevant rake routes output:

```
      pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index
            POST   /pages(.:format)          pages#create
   new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
  edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
       page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
            PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
            DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy
```

And my config/routes.rb:

```
  Portfolio::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users

  root to: 'pages#home'

  match '/signup',   to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '/admin',    to: 'admin#index'
  match '/new',      to: 'pages#new'
  match '/edit',     to: 'pages#edit'

  match '*path', :controller => 'redirect', :action => 'index'
```

And the controller action, just in case.

```
  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I thought I'd also give the view, where the path is called:

```
 <% Page.where("parent_id IS NULL").each do |page| %>
   <li>
     <%= link_to page.title, page %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", page, edit_page_path  %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", page, method: :delete,
                                 data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
```

I do have an awful habit of not seeing my typos, so if I have made a silly one it would explain why I can't fix this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_page_path(page)  %>
```

If you look closer on your routes output:

```
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
```

The route edit_page requires an :id to be passed to.

Comment: I did this and removed the page variable from the middle of the line and it works perfectly. Thanks very much! Can't believe I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

The edit link should be generated like this

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_page_path(page) %>
```

As Erez pointed out, `:id` is required which is retrieved from `page`.

Check [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to/) signatures for possible ways to pass the arguments. First/second argument is for `url` or `url_options` while third argument is for `html_options`.